# apache nifi 1.15.0 startup failure caused by sensitive property

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi

The answer on many forums is to simply "create the key". However, this also requires further maintenance because then the flow.xml.gz file cannot be easily migrated between deployments. I do not experience this on previous versions (v1.12.0 & 1.13.0).

Any thoughts on mitigating this issue?

```
Error: 
ERROR [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Clustered Configuration Found: Shared Sensitive Properties Key [nifi.sensitive.props.key] required for cluster nodes

ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There was an issue decrypting protected properties
```

Similar question: [Docker - Nifi : 1.14.0 - Startup failure - Caused by: org.apache.nifi.properties.SensitivePropertyProtectionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69217062/docker-nifi-1-14-0-startup-failure-caused-by-org-apache-nifi-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Create the key.

Don't let NiFi generate a random one, supply it from your deployment code along with all the other settings that go into nifi.properties. If you have the same key, you can copy/migrate the flow.xml.gz and share it within clusters.
This also works with an encrypted key if you provide the decryption hex key in bootstrap.conf when deploying.

The latest NiFi version has support for Hashicorp vaults. That might allow you to obtain the correct keys at runtime and share them among cluster nodes.

If you want to work without a key, you will need to use NiFi 1.13.2 or older. From the admin guide:

> Starting with version 1.14.0, NiFi requires a value for 'nifi.sensitive.props.key' in nifi.properties.
>
> The following command can be used to read an existing flow.xml.gz configuration and set a new sensitive properties key in nifi.properties:
>
> $ ./bin/nifi.sh set-sensitive-properties-key [sensitivePropertiesKey]
>
> The minimum required length for a new sensitive properties key is 12 characters.

Comment: I did, then Nifi throws another hundred errors as a result (too much to post here). I actually don't want a key or anything like this, I also can't find documentation suggesting this is required the app to run.

Comment: @kp-a I checked the docs again and updated the answer. It's way down in the admin guide at "Updating the sensitive properties key"

Comment: Thanks for the response, I can read the docs. As stated before, simply creating a key results in many many more errors.

The solution:  I created a new deployment, copy and pasted the XML, and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this error.

Create a new deployment, either import the flow file via the GUI or copy and paste the XML flow file, then restart the deployment.

In my testing, I have not seen any evidence that the sensitive key property is required.